# load em css e jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de `load` para informar ao usuário que a página esta sendo carregada.

Tenho uma página em php que monta um relatório bem grande, e ele leva em torno de 10 segundos para ser exibido. Em quanto isso a página fica em branco. O que eu quero é colocar um `load` até que a página seja carregada.

Tentei fazer assim, no inicio do php eu coloquei isso:

```
<div class="se-pre-con"><p>PROCESSANDO DADOS</p></div>
```

Coloquei antes da tag

```
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: url(../Img/Loading.gif) center no-repeat #FFFFFF;
}
.se-pre-con p {
    text-align: center;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -125px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

O no jquery esta assim:

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut();
});
```

O problema e que o load até aparece, porém ele aparece depois de uns 5 segundos. Como faço para ele aparecer e depois o php começar a carregar os dados? Tem como?

------------ EDIT

Segue minha página em php, assim vcs podem me falar se estou fazendo algo errado.

```
<!-- Loading -->
<div class="se-pre-con"><p>PROCESSANDO DADOS</p></div>

<?php
// AQUI ESTOU CONECTANDO COM O BANCO DE DADOS E MONTANDO UM ARRAY COM O RESULTADO
?>


<!-- Relatório -->
<table class="relatorio">

    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>PRODUTO</td>
        <td>QUANTIDADE</td>
        <td>VALOR</td>
    </tr>


    <?php
    // Aqui monto o relatório com o array
    foreach ($curva as $c) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $c['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $c['nome'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $c['qtd'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $c['valor'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Já tentou: $(document).ready(function () {    }); ??

Comment: Talvez o problema seja o tamanho do gif, esses 5 segundos pode ser o tempo que demora pro navegador carregar o gif, em vez disse tente colocar um <h1> só pra testar se é renderizado logo que carrega a página

Comment: Está utilizando `ajax`?

Comment: @MaxRogério não estou usando ajax

Comment: @LuKsSys já tentei remover a imagem, e o problema não e esse.

Comment: @Aline não entendi muito bem

Comment: @HugoBorges, Quantos registros são retornados nesta consulta ao banco? Não vejo nenhum motivo para a sua página demorar, então a consulta pode ser o problema.

Comment: @jlHertel a questão não e a quantidade de registro, são vários fatores. Eu resumi o relatório para postar aqui, mas nele faço vários cálculos e verificações no banco de dados. Esse e um relatório com muito dados por isso ele demora um pouco.

Comment: @HugoBorges, então fica a sugestão de carregar a página em branco e trazer os dados depois via AJAX. O unico problema é que se forem muitos dados como você mesmo falou, o AJAX não vai ser a solução. Uma terceira opção (mais feia) seria carregar o relatório dentro de um iframe, para permitir que a página externa esteja livre para mostrar a div de carregamento que você quer.

Comment: Acho que iframe não ficaria legal, acho que o AJAX seria a melhor solução. Eu gostei da sua ideia em AJAX, só não estou sabendo com usar ela no meu código. Não entendi como vou carregar os dados na tabela. Poderia dar um exemplo mais detalhado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O melhor é você fazer uma página que carrega só a div:

```
<!-- Loading -->
<div class="se-pre-con"><p>PROCESSANDO DADOS</p></div>
```

E outra página que carregue só o conteudo do relatório

```
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>PRODUTO</td>
    <td>QUANTIDADE</td>
    <td>VALOR</td>
</tr>


<?php
// Aqui monto o relatório com o array
foreach ($curva as $c) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $c['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $c['nome'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $c['qtd'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $c['valor'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Daí ficaria assim:

http://www.meusite.com.br/relatorio -> Responde só a div

http://www.meusite.com.br/relatorio-corpo -> Responde o corpo do relatório.

E com ajax você carrega o conteudo:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'http://www.meusite.com.br/relatorio-corpo',
    'success': function(responseHtml) {
         $(".se-pre-con").html(responseHtml);
     }
 });
```

----- EDIT

Lembrando que essa não é a melhor abordagem, já que irá ficar trafegando dados de HTML pela rede. O melhor seria responder os dados em JSON e montar o HTML usando Javascript

Comment: Legal, estou tentando fazer funcionar com base na sua ideia. Bom eu ja tenho os dados em JSON como faria para o javascript preencher o relatório ?

Comment: Você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

Comment: Consegui fazer da sua forma aqui. Deu certo. Mas poderia colocar um exemplo de como fazer com JSON

Comment: Você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

    $.ajax({
        'url': 'http://www.meusite.com.br/relatorio-json',
        'success': function(responseJson) {
            $.each(responseJson, function(key, value)) {
                "<tr><td>" + value.id + "</td></tr>";
             }
          }   
    });

Comment: Aqui tá melhor: https://jsfiddle.net/o39fgvk4/

Comment: qual o problema de trafegar HTML pela rede? O site usa SSL tem algum problema com, a segurança?

Comment: É mais questão de uso da banda de internet e performance. Dependendo do número de requisição é melhor diminuir o tráfego. Eu detalhei mais aqui: http://blog.toneladas.com.br/respondendo-no-stackoverflow-1.html

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que o PHP ainda está enviando a resposta ao navegador, e por este motivo, a página ainda não terminou de carregar.

Uma estratégia mais interessante é abrir o seu relatório vazio, mostrar a `div` de carregamento e só então carregar os dados do PHP, utilizando uma chamada de AJAX.

Um exemplo bem simples seria:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeIn();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'meu php',
    success: function(response) {
      /* Monte aqui o seu HTML */
      /* Ao final, remova a div novamente: */
      $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut();
    }, 
    error: function(error) {
      /* Trate os erros */
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Vou montar o html dentro do Javascript? Acho que não iria dar certo. Para facilitar eu vou editar a pergunta com minha pagina php. Se puder olhar e me explicar melhor.

Comment: @HugoBorges, como o script php vai demorar a responder, eu vejo duas opções: sentar e esperar carregar, ou fazer isso tudo via AJAX como sugeri. Você não precisa necessáriamente montar o HTML pelo Javascript, pode fazer isso tudo no php e apenas pegar este resultado e inserir novamente na DOM.

Comment: entendi, mas não sei como fazer isso na minha estrutura atual, poderia me ajudar? coloquei como estou montando o relatório.